# What are the current rooting options for Galaxy S6?

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-6, samsung-knox

I've sort of been following the development scene for the A6, enough to know that there are multiple rooting options, each with their own pros and cons. What are the current ways people are rooting their S6s?

Comment: It seems the more popular way people are rooting the S6 is via Chainfire's autoroot method. You can find more info on XDA. http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/orig-development/cf-auto-root-t3056630

Comment: Pingpong Root, Uni Kernel, Odin, CF Auto Root. Google them along with your device model and you should be good to go. Keep in mind, once you upgrade to 5.1.1 there is no way to root without tripping Knox, unless you have the T-Mobile or international variant, using the engineering bootloader ([http://wyckedroot.com/](http://wyckedroot.com/)). If you want root you need to trip knox.

Answer (score 0):

These are my options by which you can root your device:-

1. Odin (*I prefer*)
2. Kingo
3. Oneclick

See [this link](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/samsung-galaxy-s6-guide,review-2856-3.html) to know more.